# Android: populating listview from arrayadapter / arraylist

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I am making an app which is polling an XML sheet from a url through AsyncTask, so it does'nt interfere with the mainThread.

I have been able to make the connection, retrieve the xml and parse the values in a loop and add these to an arraylist.

My problem is that when the app is loading on the handset, the arraylist should be transformed to an arrayadapter and then populate the listview in the app.

I've got it to work with an hardcoded xml file, but when I try to use the parsed values from my dynamic xml, then the app fails.

This code is getting the XML sheet and adds it to an arraylist "menuItems" - this works fine

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

Log.d("beskeden", "Henter adressen: " + URL);

try{
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();            

XMLParser parser = new XMLParser(); 
String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML 
Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element 

NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM); 

// looping through all item nodes <item> 
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) { 


     HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
     map.put(KEY_NAVN, nl.item(i).getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent());
     map.put(KEY_BESKRIVELSE, nl.item(i).getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent()); 
     map.put(KEY_THETYPE, nl.item(i).getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent()); 
     map.put(KEY_THETIMER, nl.item(i).getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent()); 
     map.put(KEY_THEGRADER, nl.item(i).getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent()); 
     map.put(KEY_THESEMERE, nl.item(i).getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent()); 
     map.put(KEY_IDP, nl.item(i).getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent());                  


    Log.e("Beskeden", nl.item(i).getChildNodes().item(1).getNodeName() + ": " + nl.item(i).getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent());               
    Log.e("Beskeden", nl.item(i).getChildNodes().item(3).getNodeName() + ": " + nl.item(i).getChildNodes().item(3).getTextContent());               
    Log.e("Beskeden", nl.item(i).getChildNodes().item(5).getNodeName() + ": " + nl.item(i).getChildNodes().item(5).getTextContent());               
    Log.e("Beskeden", nl.item(i).getChildNodes().item(7).getNodeName() + ": " + nl.item(i).getChildNodes().item(7).getTextContent());

    menuItems.add(map);                 
}        


Log.d("beskeden", "Antal theer: " + nl.getLength());            
Log.d("beskeden", "Xml er blevet parset");


return true;
} catch (Exception e){
return false;
}

}
```

The following code is doing so i can't compile and test it - so frustating :/

```
//@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
//super.onPostExecute(result);
Log.d("Besked", "Post executen");

if (success) {
    Log.d("Beskeden", "SUCCES!!");
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, menuItems);
}else{
        Log.d("Beskeden", "FAIL!!");
}
```

I am a bit stuck, so any help is welcome :)

Comment: Make a custom adapter that holds the arraylist, use notifydatasetchanged to update ui based on adapters arraylist

Comment: If the app *fails* then you should post the exception/error you get when running the application. Looking at your code I see you use `this` as a reference to a `Context` in the `onPostExecute` method, but as the `onPostExecute` method is in the `AsyncTask` class `this` will point to the current task instance and NOT a valid `Context`. So obtain a valid `Context` reference for the `ArrayAdapter`(for example, if the task is a inner class in the activity you could use `YourActivityName.this`).

Comment: I used the luksprog reply and this thread [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034587/error-with-arrayadapter-in-asynctask[/link] to figure out a solution that worked with updating the listview on the ui.

Comment: I did move the arraylist up to class level and changed the arrayadapter in postexecute

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(Forside.this, R.layout.list_item, menuItems);
      setListAdapter(adapter);

Comment: the output on each row is like: 
{thenavn=blabla, thedesc=blablabla}

how do i format the content, so i would be:

Thenavn (headline size) [linebreak]
Thedesc (normal paragraph size)

:)